# How to get the textvalue of each dynamically created row in UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

As shown in below image,i created a prototype cell with label and textfield in tableviewController.

[image]

Each row is created at runtime as shown below. When user clicks SAVE button all the details like Course detail,Registration id, Username and passowrd should be saved in respective varaibles. But it does not work. It stores value of last textfield in all variables.

How do i get text value in each row of the table.

// Row creation code

```
cell variable is global
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        switch(indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0 :
                 cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RegCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RegCell
         cell.configure("Course detail", txtValue: "Enter course.")
                 break;

            case 1 :
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RegCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RegCell
                cell.configure("Registration ID", txtValue: "Enter registration id.")
                cell.txtIpValue.tag = 1
                break;

            case 2 :
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RegCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RegCell
                cell.configure("Username ", txtValue: "Username")
                cell.txtIpValue.tag = 2
                break;

            case 3 :
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RegCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RegCell
                cell.configure("Password ", txtValue: "Password")
                cell.txtIpValue.tag = 2
                break;

            default :
                break;

        }


        return cell
    }
```

// Save button code

```
func saveButtonClicked() {

        if(cell.txtIpValue.tag == 1)
        {
            strCourse = cell.txtIpValue.text
        }

    if(cell.txtIpValue.tag == 2)
        {
            strID = cell.txtIpValue.text
        }

    if(cell.txtIpValue.tag == 3)
        {
            strUsername = cell.txtIpValue.text
        }

    if(cell.txtIpValue.tag == 1)
        {
            strPassword = cell.txtIpValue.text
        }      

}
```

// Regcell

```
class RegCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var txtIpValue: UITextField
    @IBOutlet var lblstr: UILabel

    func configure(lblValue : String,txtValue :String)) {

        lblstr.text = lblValue
        txtIpValue.text = txtValue
    } 

}
```

All code is in swift. Please if possible give an example.

Comment: in your app 4 cells are fixed?

Comment: Where is the cell variable coming from in saveButtonClicked ?

Comment: @Chetan Prajapati - yes

Comment: @deadbeef - sorry forgot to give information that cell variable is global.

Comment: then why you are not taking static cells instead dynamic. bcoz 4 cell is reliable for memory. not big deal. and another thing in your above code there is many mistakes too

Comment: You're going to have to show us the entire code. I don't understand what is the use case of that global since you have only one variable but 4 cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over all cells in your tableView.
Assuming you have only one section, try this:

**Update** : Using label texts as keys for the values - you might want to think about finding constant values for that

```
func save() {
    var fields = NSMutableDictionary();
    for rowIndex in 0...self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) {
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: rowIndex, inSection: 0);
        let cell : RegCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath);
        fields.setObject(cell.txtIpValue.text, forKey: cell.lblstr.text)
    }
    // ... here fields will contain all values, using the lblstr.text as key
    let username = fields["Username "];
}
```

Comment: I suggest you put an identifier property into the RegCell, such as "user_name" or "password" and use them as keys in the mutableDictionary i suggested above.
This would separate it from the actual displayed label text.

Comment: very nice answer you saved my day @MarkHim